# Redirect all standard out for rest of script

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I have a bash script that I want to redirect all the rest of the output into a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
# the part I don't know  ${file}
echo spo 
echo car

cat ${file}
```

output should be spo\ncar\n

Comment: output redirection is made by adding ,`> out 2>&1` at end of your execution command.

Answer (score 9):

If you redirect stdout for the rest of the script, then that would include the "cat" command, so you wouldn't see its output, `$file` could fill up indefinitely with recursive copies of itself (and would if it wouldn't be so small as to let `cat` see the end of it before starting to write to it).

To redirect stdout from now on, you simply do:

```
exec > "$file"
```

But here maybe you want:

```
#! /bin/bash -
{
  echo spo 
  echo car
} > "$file"

cat < "$file"
```

You can also do things like:

```
exec 3>&1 # save stdout as fd 3
exec > "$file"
echo spo
echo car
exec >&3 3>&- # restore stdout and close fd 3
cat < "$file"
```

(and by the way, the above is what modern shells do internally when you redirect a compound command like `{ some; code; } > ...` (though they use a fd above 10 and set the O_CLOEXEC flag on it so that executed commands don't see it), while the Bourne shell would fork a subshell in that case)

Also note that in the code above, you don't **have** to restore stdout for the rest of the script, you can do it for the `cat` command only:

```
cat < "$file" >&3 3>&-
```

(the `3>&-` (closing fd 3) is not necessary as `cat` doesn't use its fd 3 anyway but is good practice in the general case, and strictly speaking, we'd have to add it to every command to emulate the O_CLOEXEC behavior of the shell).