# Redirect output to either stdout or a file (not both)

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, ksh

I want to create a script that, when called interactively, writes to stdout, but if called from another script and variable EVENT_LOGGER is defined by the calling script, writes to file EVENT_LOGGER.

There's probably an easy way to do this but it's just not coming to me.  I can certainly add this logic to every place where output is generated:

```
if [[ -f $EVENT_LOGGER ]]
then
   echo "Some message" >> $EVENT_LOGGER
else
   echo "Some message"
fi
```

but that'll add a lot of bulk to the script.

I was hoping I could do something like this instead:

```
if [[ ! -f $EVENT_LOGGER ]]
then
   EVENT_LOGGER = "&1"
fi
```

Then, all output commands would be:

```
echo "Some message" >> $EVENT_LOGGER
```

and they'd go to either the file or stdout, whichever EVENT_LOGGER point to.

That didn't work.  Is there another way to have $EVENT_LOGGER resolve to stdout?

I'm using ksh93 on AIX 7.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect all standard out for rest of script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56584/redirect-all-standard-out-for-rest-of-script)

Comment: @MichaelHomer Not really, this question calls for different answers because there's the conditional aspect.

Comment: @Gilles I'm not sure that "wrap an `if` around it" is a material difference (especially when the question already asks what to put into the `if`...).

Comment: @MichaelHomer The point is that there are methods whch are not “wrap an if around it”.

Answer (score 4):

On many Unix variants, you can access standard output via the file name `/dev/stdout`, thus:

```
if [[ -z $EVENT_LOGGER ]]; then
  EVENT_LOGGER=/dev/stdout
fi
…
echo >>"$EVENT_LOGGER" 'This is a log message'
```

However I'm not sure if it's available on AIX. See [Portability of "> /dev/stdout"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36403/portability-of-dev-stdout) and [Unix systems without /dev/stdin, /dev/stdout, and /dev/stderr?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338667/unix-systems-without-dev-stdin-dev-stdout-and-dev-stderr)

Alternatively, keep all logging to stdout and optionally redirect stdout to a file. If you call the `exec` builtin with no command name but with redirections, this sets the redirections for the remainder of the script.

```
if [[ -n $EVENT_LOGGER ]]; then
  exec >>"$EVENT_LOGGER"
fi
…
echo 'This is a log message'
```

Note that output from programs called by the script will go to the same log file. If you don't want that, then do the logging on another file descriptor.

```
if [[ -n $EVENT_LOGGER ]]; then
  exec 3>>"$EVENT_LOGGER"
else
  exec 3>&1
fi
…
echo >&3 'This is a log message'
```

Yet another approach is to define a function in different ways depending on what is desired.

```
if [[ -n $EVENT_LOGGER ]]; then
  log () {
    echo "$*" >>"$EVENT_LOGGER"
  }
else
  log () {
    echo "$*"
  }
fi
…
log 'This is a log message'
```

Whatever you do, I recommend using a function. This way, if you ever want to change how logging works (e.g. both to the terminal and to a file, add colors, make it conditional, …), it'll be a lot easier.

Some general notes:

- The test `-f` tests whether a file exists. This is not a good test here. Instead, test if the variable is non-empty, with `-n` (`-z` tests whether it's empty).
- You can't put spaces around the `=` sign in a variable assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
$ cat interactive.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -n "$EVENT_LOGGER" ]]; then
    exec 1>>"$EVENT_LOGGER"
fi
date
echo "hello world"
```

The magic sauce: `exec 1>>"$EVENT_LOGGER"` redirects stdout for the duration of the script.

Demo:

1. variable not defined, output to stdout

   ```
   $ bash interactive.sh
   Sat Jan  6 19:06:02 EST 2018
   hello world
   ```
2. variable defined, output to file

   ```
   $ env EVENT_LOGGER="./event.logger" bash interactive.sh
   $ cat event.logger
   Sat Jan  6 19:06:13 EST 2018
   hello world
   ```

Comment: Thanks Gilles and Glenn.   I checked and found that AIX 7.1 does support redirecting to /dev/stdout  (AIX 6.1 does NOT).  I think I'll go that route to redirecting the output only because, in my mind, it's more obvious what's being done.  However, the 'exec 1>>$file' is an interesting use of exec.

Comment: I have never used the exec command before and reading about it because of thread has been educational. :-)   If 'exec' is being used explicitly to run another file in the same process context as the caller, why not just do a ". some-file" versus "exec some-file"?   Are they the same?  I'm sure I just don't understand fully what either does.  Thanks again.

Comment: In this context, we're providing exec with a redirection. That takes effect for the currently running script. The difference between `. some-file` and `exec some-file`: `.` (or source) executes the named file and then continues processing the current script; `exec` *replaces* the current process with some-file, so when some-file exits, we cannot continue with the current script.